# Trying to add content after the closest label but I think i'm wrong

Tags: jquery, html, closest

I have a custom form where I need to add some content after a label, see below.

I have these lines of code:

```js
$("input[name='cpy_name']").closest('.control-label').insertAfter('Some text');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group has-feedback" style="display: block;"> 
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Company</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-4">
       <input type="text" name="cpy_name" class="form-control" maxlength="200" value="">
      </div>
</div>
```

I thought using 'closest' I'll find the `.control-label`... Why it's not working, please clarify me.

Which selector I need to use here?

Thank you in adavance,

Comment: `closest()` finds parent nodes, as it says in the API documentation (http://api.jquery.com/closest/).  The control-label is not a parent of the input.

Comment: yes you are right, but how can I select the `control-label`?

Comment: How, in terms of tree traversals, are the two elements related?  You know how to use closest to find parents, so what operations can be used to navigate between siblings, or find children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`closest()` finds parent nodes only and `has-feedback` is not an parent node, so try this:

```js
$("input[name='cpy_name']").closest('.has-feedback').find('.control-label').after(' Some text');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group has-feedback" style="display: block;"> 
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Company</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-4">
       <input type="text" name="cpy_name" class="form-control" maxlength="200" value="">
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's what's I was looking for... Thank you.  I was just a little bit confused, thank you for your help!

Comment: @aflyzer please take some time to go over the traversal methods (http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).  Recognising how elements are related to each other, and what operations are available to get from one node to another, can help you with your developmental process.

Comment: @Taplar a nice advice, I appreciate this :)